# Dynamic Text Box in PHP Mail

Tags: php, javascript, radio-button, html-email

I have an order form that is quite complex where you can order products form radio buttons.

I also have a text box where the price gets calculated live on the page depeding on what you are selecting.

This is done by using this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var frm = document.forms.myForm;
frm.onchange = function(e) {
    var tot = 0;
    for( var i = 0, l = frm.elements.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        if( frm.elements[i].checked ) {
            tot += parseFloat( frm.elements[i].getAttribute('data-price') );
        }  
    }
    document.getElementById('total').value = ( tot.toFixed(2) );
}
})
    </script>
```

The box is here

```
<input id="total" name="total2" class="total-box" type="text">
```

But for some reason the info is not being added into the mail that gets sent, everything else gets sent fine.

In my mail script I have

```
$total2 = $_REQUEST['total2'] ;
```

and

```
<tr><td style="border-bottom:1px solid #7e7e7e;">Price</td><td style="border-bottom:1px solid #7e7e7e;">'.$total2.' </td></tr>
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: What is appearing in your email? Is the box coming through empty, or with the wrong total?

Comment: @andrewsi The box is coming through empty, I can put the scripts onto pastebin if it will help you take a look?

Comment: Could you try adding a default value to the input box, and retrying? something like `value="0"` should do the trick. I suspect that when the form is submitted, it's picking up the HTML for the form, and ignoring the changes that the javascript has made to the value of the form elements.

Comment: @andrewsi After I set a defualt value everything seems to work fine after it has updated. Thank You :)

Comment: Huh. Not what I was expecting, in that case - I wonder if it was just that the input had no value set in the HTML, and when the form was submitted, there was nothing to submit. Nevertheless - glad to have helped!

Comment: You should not calculate the price on your page using JavaScript. You should at least validate it on the server side - otherwise somebody can send you arbitrary prices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use javascript the value of the input field will not be set for the server $_POST data. So you are looking for some kind of serialization (i.e javascript that takes all the input values and sends them through $_POST, you could do it manually but its tedious)

If you want to stick to pure javascript: http://code.google.com/p/form-serialize/ might help out. Otherwise look at some framework and serialize(), most frameworks have it implemented as it is used quite often.

My suggestion would be to recreate your price generation script in PHP aswel, so you just submit which form buttons have been pressed (which you don't need serialize for) and then just get the price from that on the backend. A lot safer too!